# SSRS Report-outputting ''Blank'' rather than 0 for end user

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, report

First off, I am new and just learning about databases and reporting functionality.

Background: Let's say that I am an end user and I have requested a report from my IT department. I know that my company uses SQL server and they generate SSRS reports frequently.The SQL Server database is connected to a PIM(product data) application.  Within the PIM there is a numeric field holding a quantity of bulbs.  In the event that there is no bulb, that field is left blank.  I do not have access to our database or the reporting parameters.  I am at the mercy of someone else essentially.

When I receive my report, I see zeros '0' for every item that doesn't have a bulb.  That is not the desired output, I want to see the field as a 'blank' just as it is in our PIM system. When I expressed this to the report writer, he informed me that this could not be done because that is a numeric field.

Does this seem correct?  Please help!! I am fighting an uphill battle.  I have a job to do and it relies heavily on IT support.  I now have to go to my boss and tell her that this can't be done.  I also understand that I can manually manipulate the report myself in excel but this is time consuming and if this can be handled before the report hits my inbox, that would be ideal.  If there is a solution that someone out there can relay to me, I would be so appreciative-Thanks!!

Comment: It is possible that the while interface has you leave the field blank, the database defaults the field value to 0. Maybe he thought you wanted to change the field rather than what's displayed on the report. Most DBAs avoid NULLs in a numeric field - it makes math(s) hard.

Comment: Thanks for your input!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the report is definitely generated in SSRS, it is absolutely possible to set zero values as a blank field.  To me, it sounds as if the person responsible just doesn't want to make the change because it's a fairly simple fix.  It's as simple as opening the properties window of whatever field needs to be fixed. Since the field is numeric, you would want to format the textbox as a number anyways.  The highlighted option displays where this change can be made.  There's actually three default options for `Show zero as:` being blank, a dash(`-`), or displaying `(None)`.

[image: example]

Comment: Steve-O, you just saved me!  Thank you and I will def pay it forward.  Have a great weekend!!